# How can I export complete profile from Linkedin?

Tags: pdf, export, linkedin-api

I was looking at the Linkedin profile - PDF export feature. I found few of the sections such as Projects, Skills ... are not getting exported in PDF. Did I missed any settings change ?

Also, I was wondering "Will it be okay if we use Linkedin exported profile as a CV ?" CV that we send to recruiters ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming or software engineering. It is about how to do something on a particular social media site.

Answer (score 13):

LinkedIn has changed its **Save As PDF** functionality since January 2017. As you can read here : [Printing a Profile](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4281/printing-a-profile?lang=en) clearly states that not all profile sections will appear in the PDF after export. There are a lot of Google Chrome Extensions or apps ([ResponsiveCV](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-cv-resume-make/cnnffgdlkepdhppahlfeojbpjlbbpgep?hl=en)) for converting LinkedIn profile to a resume but none of them do the required task properly.
However, I used a hack kind of solution to this. If you don't want any other app to scan your LinkedIn profile data and if you are a software developer comfortable with Developer Options in a browser, you can go to view your complete profile and inspect elements to delete the unwanted sections(Remove header, footer, right table, etc.). Once you're done removing unwanted elements, **print the webpage**.

Comment: Any idea how also to quickly make it take the full width of the page?

Comment: thanks, this helped it, it was work but final result was good

Comment: @Snowcat I need to add my profile picture.

Answer (score 10):

**Update: 2020-05-11**

Now Top Skills, Languages, Publications, Honors-Awards and Certifications are included in the built in PDF-generator. Projects and Courses are still missing though.

**Original:**

As you mention the biggest drawback with the **Save to PDF** functionality is that Skills, Projects, Courses, Languages, Publications and Certifications are not exported among others. This information can however be exported to `.csv`. Do this by going to Settings & Privacy -> Privacy -> How LinkedIn uses your data -> Download your data -> Pick and choose: Select the data files you're most interested in. -> Select Profile (You can of course export other data as well if you want). After around 10 minutes you will receive an email with a download link.

[image]

Example of Profile export `.zip`:

[image]

Answer (score -8):

Well, the 'developper' solution maybe be a bit too long..
I've got an other solution which is the following:

> -step 1: toggle data you wanna display
>
> -step 2: make a screenshot of your page (with screenshot tool not "full screenshot" => hit 'windows' key then write scr and windows will propose you that tool)
>
> -step 3: create a word document
>
> -step 4: paste your screenshot inside the word document
>
> -repeat all these step until all of your content got inside your word file
>
> -finally: export your Word document into PDF document

I hope you'll enjoy this solution :)

Regards

Maxime

Comment: Do not ever create a resume from screenshots.